# Значение placeholder в зависимости от разрешения экрана

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, css

Делаю адаптивный дизайн и столкнулся с такой проблемой, нужно чтобы значение placeholder менялось в зависимости от разрешения экрана. Подскажите, пожалуйста, скрипт.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

Это можно реализовать, как с помощью CSS и в частности медиа-запросов:

```css
input.large {
  display: inline-block;
}
input.small {
  display: none;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  input.large {
    display: none;
  }
  input.small {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

```html
<input class="large" name="somename[]" placeholder="For large">
<input class="small" name="somename[]" placeholder="For small">
```

Так и с помощью JS. И в этом случае, есть несколько вариантов. Например, базироваться на событии resize:

```js
var inp = document.querySelector('.my_input');
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
  inp.setAttribute('placeholder', this.innerWidth >= 600 ? 'For large' : 'For small');
});
window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
```

```html
<input class="my_input" name="somename" placeholder="For large">
```

Вышеуказанный вариант, можно записать еще так:

```js
var inp = document.querySelector('.my_input');
window.addEventListener('resize', changePlaceholder);
changePlaceholder.call(window);

function changePlaceholder() {
  inp.setAttribute('placeholder', this.innerWidth >= 600 ? 'For large' : 'For small');
}
```

```html
<input class="my_input" name="somename" placeholder="For large">
```

А можно использовать метод matchMedia(). Это своего рода медиа-запросы в JS:

```js
var inp = document.querySelector('.my_input'),

  mediaQuery = window.matchMedia("screen and (max-width: 600px)");
mediaQuery.addListener(changePlaceholder);

function changePlaceholder(mq) {
  if (mq.matches) {
    inp.setAttribute('placeholder', 'For small');
  } else {
    inp.setAttribute('placeholder', 'For large');

  }
}
changePlaceholder(mediaQuery);
```

```html
<input class="my_input" name="somename" placeholder="For large">
```

Я думаю, что можно еще найти парочку способов. Какие-то будут более кроссбраузерными, какие-то - нет. Выбор остается за вами.